# Build.gradle error A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'

Tags: dependencies, build.gradle, ionic4, pusher

i got the error A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.pusher:pusher-java-client:1.5.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

every time i run cordova build android

the code i entered was 
compile 'com.pusher:pusher-java-client:1.5.0'
in the dependency in build.gredle i cant find out the issue

code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        compile 'com.pusher:pusher-java-client:1.5.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which `build.gradle` file are you using?
Compile cannot be used in the project level file - instead use the module specific file. For example:

```
AndroidProject\app\build.gradle
```